# Http delete method using jQuery ajax on django rest backend fails on Safari, but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I want to use django rest framework as backend and jQuery in the frontend to post and delete. Using $.ajax POST works fine. But delete call fails on Safari but works in Chrome. Here is the sample code:

django models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class Article(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/articles/', views.ArticleList.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/articles/<int:pk>', views.ArticleItem.as_view()),
]
```

views.py:

```
class ArticleList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Articles.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class ArticleItem(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    query set = Articles.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

serializer.py

```
class ArticleSerializer(serialisers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'content', 'create_date')
```

jQuery:

```
# on delete link
$("#talk").on('click', 'a[id^=delete-]', function() {
  var pk = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
  delete_article(pk);
});

function delete_article(pk){
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/v1/articles/"+pk,
        type: "DELETE",
        data: { pk: pk },
        success: function(son) {
            $('#post-'+pk).hide();
            console.log("delete successful")
        },
    })
 };
```

In Safari 11.0.1, in console it only shows "0: undefined". It is not going into success loop.

In Chrome delete function is successful.

Comment: **in console it only shows "0: undefined".** where is this output coming from ?

Comment: I have no idea as Chrome is not showing this output.

Comment: What do you mean, "this"?You can use ' this' while building or iterating all class members.**Did you see this? You're not in my office, how do you know what I'm talking about ?**

Comment: yes you are right. what I mean this is the output "0: undefined". So my previous comment should be: "I have no idea as Chrome is not showing the output 0: undefined".

Comment: `$("#talk").on('click', 'a[id^=delete-]', function(this) {` Maybe it solves your problem, maybe... **OR**  `<a onclick="deleteThis(this);">Delete This</a>` then `function deleteThis(f){delete_article(f.attr('id').split('-')[1]);}`